# Why isn't possible to mix JOIN ANSI syntax and JOIN with WHERE in OracleSQL?

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, where-clause

I'm having trouble understanding why the first request returns : Error DB 904 : ORA-00904 invalid identifier

My guess is because the WHERE is after the LEFT OUTER JOIN so the "compiler" can't decide which JOIN to do first.

```
--This request does not work : Error DB 904 : ORA-00904
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.web_email,
       t2.id,
       t2.mail
FROM   table1 t1,
       table2 t2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
                    ON ( t1.id = t3.id )
WHERE  t1.web_email = t2.mail
       AND t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER  BY t1.web_email,
          t1.id;

--By using only JOIN clauses, this request executes as expected
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.web_email,
       t2.id,
       t2.mail
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN table2 t2
               ON ( t1.web_email = t2.mail )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 t3
                    ON ( t1.id = t3.id )
WHERE  t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER  BY t1.web_email,
          t1.id;

--By using only FROM and WHERE, this request executes as expected
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.web_email,
       t2.id,
       t2.mail
FROM   table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       table3 t3
WHERE  t1.web_email = t2.mail
       AND t1.id = t3.id(+)
       AND t1.id <> t2.id
ORDER  BY t1.web_email,
          t1.id;
```

So, why did the first request failed ? What's the name of that behavior ? And why does Oracle's error is so misleading ? Can't it detect why ?

Comment: Why spend time worrying over the *why* when you already know how to use the ANSI version, which has existed for over 20 years and is already implemented? Since you know how to fix the problem, isn't *any* answer you obtain here purely some piece of trivia?

Comment: You are right, this is surprising as a comma in the join clause can easily be replaced with `CROSS JOIN` and with that the query is running fine. So it seems the parser has unexpected problems. Doesn't matter much, because nowadays one should not use the pre-1992 joins anymore anyway, but a glitch nonetheless.

Comment: Scope issue, join chains are evaluated before comma separated tables. I.e in `...t1, t2 left join t3 on...`, the on clause has no access to t1 columns.

Comment: In case you want to read more on the issue (which indeed seems like a parser glitch): https://sqlfascination.com/2013/08/17/oracle-ansi-vs-old-style-joins/

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Better comprehension of how things work is never useless IMO. I was really surprised that it didn't work and tend to use old-school JOIN when the link is mandatory whereas I prefer ANSI JOIN when the link is optional.

Comment: @TomH indeed really helpful insight ! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? Just stick to explicit `JOIN` operator for everything. Forget about those outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause

Comment: "I ... tend to use old-school JOIN ..." - I would *strongly* advise you get out of that habit. You're effectively engineering a situation where anyone encountering your work (now, or in the future) will be asking themselves questions such as "if they're this far behind on SQL, where else are they using outdated methods or practices?"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: why spend time worrying "why"?  Because you need to know what a query is doing to refactor it into ansi syntax.